# Add more elements in php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an Array like this

```
        $array1 = [
            0 => [
                'category_name' => 'Example 1'
            ],
            1 => [
                'category_name' => 'Example 2'
            ],
            2 => [
                'category_name' => 'Example 3'
            ],
        ];
```

I want to add more keys in each index of this array and finally I want to get output like this

```
        $array2 = [
            0 => [
                'import_id' => 10,
                'country_id' => 1,
                'category_name' => 'Example 1'
            ],
            1 => [
                'import_id' => 10,
                'country_id' => 1,
                'category_name' => 'Example 2'
            ],
            2 => [
                'import_id' => 10,
                'country_id' => 1,
                'category_name' => 'Example 3'
            ],
        ];
```

But I don't want to use any loop to do this. is it possible ??

Comment: You can't add values to subarrays without loopin outer array. So, loop, it's not a rocketscience.

Comment: In any case it will be a  loop, even if you use array_map or something else

Comment: The only way to do it without loop is to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One long way without using a loop :)

```
    $array2 = array_fill(0, count($array1), ['import_id' => 10, 'country_id' => 1]);
    $array2 = array_replace_recursive($array2, $array1);
```

[**demo**](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b0OX)